# iOS 7 Views layout & Translucency effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I have several issues. Basically I want to rebuild this view:

[image]

While rebuilding this I m getting weird behaviors. Let's get started:

First my progress so far:

**Device Screenshot:**

[image]

**My ViewControllers structure (Storyboard):**

[image]

Well step by step:

**Navigation Bar**

I tried to make it transparent and I think it would normally work, but as you see in my structure I put a UIView over my background-imageview (Big profile picture) that simulate a alpha overlay. As you can see in my Device-Screenshot the Navigation Bar cuts of the overlay. So any idea how to fix that?

Code:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                                                               forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
```

**View Positioning**

As you can maybe see only the background-profile-image goes behind the Navigation Bar, but the rounded image and text-labels have the same top margin from the Navigation Bar. Shouldn't it be also effected by the translucency of the Navigation Bar? Any hints would be great.

Also the UIView that act also as alpha overlay don't go that much down to fill the image. Even I set all the exact same heights.

You can't see it on these images, but the View that contains all the counting labels overlaps the background-imageview (The background-imageview shouldn't even go that far down, very strange!).

You guys are my last hope. Else I have throw this awesome design ;(

Comment: Are you using autolayout? Not using it could account for views resizing differently.

Comment: @CleverError god point, but i'm using it... Also i tried to turn it off, but it is Storyboard wide and thats not good. My other views are autolayout based...

Answer (score 0):

Your dim view should be attached to the top of the superview and not the top layout guide.
You could post your constraints if you want more help.

Answer (score 0):

Its looking good. You're almost there! The problem might be that you have a `UIScrollView` inside your view controller's view and that it is respecting the content insets applied by a navigation controller (assuming there is one because I spy a navigation item in your storyboard).

Try setting this on your view controller:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```